# Cannot set direction property of Azure function

Tags: azure, function, triggers, servicebus, direction

OK, I have done significant googling on this matter now. I am trying to do something remarkably simple sounding, but which just isn't working... attach an *Azure function* as a consumer of a *Topic* on a *Service Bus*. However this is failing because I cannot properly configure the function, and by default it doesn't set up the trigger with an 'in' direction.

Now I have tried everything here, I know it should should be possible through the *ServiceBusTrigger* Attribute however this isn't behaving like it is described on other articles. The constructor to *ServiceBusTrigger* has but 2 overloads, and I can specify only the *Connection*, the *Service Bus Name* and *Topic Name*. As I cannot now update 'function.json', it actually does everything to prevent you from doing so. I cannot set the direction property and thus cannot in fact setup a function to be triggered by a service bus, from code.

I can get slightly further if I create through portal, but that then is crashing on trying to get a stream from a HTTPRequest and I cannot debug to find out what's going on.

I am using **Extensions.ServiceBus (4.1.1)** and **SDK.functions (3.0.7)**.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: additionally, I am using VS2019 (Enterprise if that matters), and .Net Core 3.1 .

Answer (score 1):

If you write functions based on the C # class library, then the direction will not defined in function.json. In fact it will get direction according to the dll file generated after your function is compiled. When you use trigger in the declaration part of the C # function, then it is "direction in".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# azure function, you don't need to point the direction. About c# function sample, you could refer to this sample: [Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp) and [output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp).

The function.json file will be generated automatically after you build your function, you could find it in the debug or release folder. And in this file, it doesn't include the direction information.

More detail you could refer to this doc:[Autogenerated function.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#autogenerated-functionjson).